# Error Jquery no identifico

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp

Creo que todo viene de las llamadas asíncronas pero no consigo identificar que sucede.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Request URL: http://localhost/app/pagines/pacientes-0.asp?id=919
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 217.112.91.96:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 2644
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 04 Aug 2018 19:20:46 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: dadaproaffinity=fa10cba727ee31e2dc736a2a6997fcbc2562ee7228fa0d7d0c88859e1fd2e0ba; ASPSESSIONIDACBRRAQB=CCLJMAABPKKLJJDBOMNMJILH; ASPSESSIONIDQQSDRDRC=JJINLKJBHNCMLECKNAGEJKMG; ASPSESSIONIDSSRCTASD=GGAFEGDCHLCILJLMLAEAPIBC; ASPSESSIONIDSQQBSCRC=EPBNIMECNBIJPJKJBHDEONGL; ASPSESSIONIDSCTDTSCS=COHHCMOCHKONPFEDALDDFKDJ; ASPSESSIONIDCSQAQQBR=ACFNONOCOKKMGNODHCDGHGEI; ASPSESSIONIDASQDQRAQ=FDOLHOOCCMLKEKEIGJOHFKPD; ASPSESSIONIDCSSATQBQ=CLLHHAPCEBDPBJDJBCPFIOHN; ASPSESSIONIDAQQDTQBQ=BLENMDPCHIIGBMHKLLFIEJDL; ASPSESSIONIDCSSDSRBR=ODBFCNPCKKINDONINCKHEPHA; ASPSESSIONIDAQQATRAR=OEBNDOPCMOMEHDGFJHEPBBNO
Host: localhost
Referer: http://localhost/app/inici.asp?p=pacientes&id=919
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
id: 919
```

Comment: Hola, sí no me equivoco estas posicionado sobre el archivo jquery-1.8.3.js que indica el error interno dentro de ese archivo, pero deberías posicionarte sobre el .asp. O sino ampliar los GET (al lado tienen una flechita) que muestra mas información para que podamos ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: te invito a colocar el código en formato de texto, es decir copialo y pegalo así como el error, pues la imagen no es muy clara que digamos

Comment: @JuanjooTocino Ya esta la info, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Negativo, el problema está en el lado del server. Usa POSTMAN y ejecuta un HTTP GET a cada una de las consultas HTTP que muestras incompletas, realiza un debugging en el archivo `.asp` Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la ruta de la petición del servidor, el error 500 significa que el servidor te dice que algo anda mal, puede ser la cantidad de parámetros, los tipos de dato que estas enviando no son los correctos, si la llamada hace referencia a una conexión a una BBDD revisa que se este conectndo de forma correcta.

Es lo que e me ocurre con los datos que posteaste.

Comment: El tema de la DB esta bien, puedo insertar y todo lo demás, el problema esta en las llamadas asíncronas, todo funciona menos eso.